# How to use Terminator's Options?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, xubuntu, terminator

Terminator has one option http://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator

```
--working-directory=DIR
Set the terminal's working directory
```

I want to open my Terminator within a specific directory each time and I think this is the option to do that.

But I don't know where to change/add this setting.

Currently every-time I open Terminator after that I need to type `cd project_directory_name`

I want to open this automatically each time I open new Terminator window or I split in same window

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

[image]

```
cd /path/to/your/directory; bash
```

Comment: this is using bash instead Prezto

Comment: This is working thanks. I changed ;bash to ;zsh.

is it also possible to run different command in different tab? . I have a layout which open 3 tab by default

Comment: This is also possible look at this great answer http://superuser.com/a/610048, but to get this work you have to remove the option "Run a custom command instead of my shell" (undo my suggestions which I have described above in my answer) then you can set a command for each tab in the layout settings how terdon described in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new launcher for Terminator with your custom settings:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop /tmp/terminator-cd.desktop
# Replace Exec=terminator with Exec=terminator --working-dir=/path/to/dir
vim /tmp/terminator-cd.desktop
chmod +x /tmp/terminator-cd.desktop
desktop-file-install --dir=~/.local/share/applications /tmp/terminator-cd.desktop
```

This should [add an icon to your launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_a_.desktop_file_to_the_Unity_Launcher). You can manually edit the `terminator-cd.desktop` file and change the display name or icon to distinguish it easily.